# Sagepay Form Integration 3.0, send logo

Tags: php, opayo

I have a question.

The problem is that i have multiples sites using the same account in sagepay.

And I want one logo for each site in the payment pages.

Can I send my logo in the parameters (using Form Integration) ?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not - logos are held at the vendor account level. It might be worth contacting your account manager (or Sage Pay customer services) - they may be able to provide you with additional vendor accounts, so that you can configure each separately.